# Scripts for LaTeX

Tags: latex

I would like to know what scripts for LaTeX mean and what they exactly do. 
For example, I saw a LaTeX document which said:

> "Typesetting using KOMA-Script and LaTeX 2e"

What are these scripts exactly used for and where can I find help using these scripts?

Comment: Might want to post this on http://tex.stackexchange.com/?as=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[“KOMA-Script”](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/) is the name of a collection of popular document classes for LaTeX which replace the standard document classes (`article`, `report`, `book` etc.). It’s got nothing to do with “scripts” in the conventional sense in programming.

For further information, type `texdoc koma` into a terminal window.